# Flask/uWSGI/MariaDB running under Supervisor stops working almost daily

Tags: nginx, flask, uwsgi, mariadb, supervisord

I'm running a Flask app via uWSGI which is managed by Supervisor (and the webserver is using Nginx).

The whole setup seems to work perfectly, however, I notice that every day or two, my flask app starts throwing 500 errors (which means there is a Sqlalchemy db.commit() error) and I can't recover until I go in and reload uwsgi, after which, everything works perfectly again. To reload, I typically kill the uwsgi processes, and supervisor brings them back in and it's fine. Once I've gotten it to work by just 'touch'ing the wsgi file.

Also strangely, whenever I run supervisor with processes=1, it automatically loads TWO uwsgi instances. The first PID is the one logged as being operated by supervisor, and the other doesn't register anywhere. However, regardless of this, killing the 2nd process - it always comes back.

Below is my uwsgi startup command run by supervisor

```
[program:{{ app_name }}]
command=/usr/local/bin/uwsgi
        --socket=/tmp/{{ app_name }}.sock
        --logto={{ log_dir }}/application.log
        --home={{ site_dir }}/env
        --pythonpath={{ site_dir }}
        --virtualenv={{ env_path }}
        --wsgi-file={{ webapps_dir }}/manage.py
        --callable={{ wsgi_callable }}
        --max-requests=1000
        --master
        --processes=1
        --uid={{ deployment_user }}
        --gid=www-data
        --chmod-socket=664
        --chown-socket={{ deployment_user }}:www-data
directory={{ webapps_dir }}
autostart=true
autorestart=true
```

**EDIT:** Here is the error that's spit out from the server.

```
2015-03-19 15:03:38,389 ERROR: Exception on /api/v1/account/login [POST] [in /var/www/website.com/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py:1423]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/www/website.com/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1817, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/var/www/website.com/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1477, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/var/www/website.com/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask_cors.py", line 272, in wrapped_function
    return cors_after_request(app.make_response(f(*args, **kwargs)))
  File "/var/www/website.com/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1381, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/var/www/website.com/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1475, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/var/www/website.com/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1461, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/var/www/website.com/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask_classy.py", line 200, in proxy
    response = view(**request.view_args)
  File "./webportal/account/api.py", line 34, in login_user
    user = auth.authenticate(username=email, password=password)
  File "/var/www/website.com/server/webportal/auth.py", line 23, in authenticate
    user = User.query.filter_by(email=username).first()
  File "/var/www/website.com/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 2367, in first
    ret = list(self[0:1])
  File "/var/www/website.com/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 2228, in __getitem__
    return list(res)
  File "/var/www/website.com/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 2438, in __iter__
    return self._execute_and_instances(context)
  File "/var/www/website.com/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 2453, in _execute_and_instances
    result = conn.execute(querycontext.statement, self._params)
  File "/var/www/website.com/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 729, in execute
    return meth(self, multiparams, params)
  File "/var/www/website.com/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/elements.py", line 322, in _execute_on_connection
    return connection._execute_clauseelement(self, multiparams, params)
  File "/var/www/website.com/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 826, in _execute_clauseelement
    compiled_sql, distilled_params
  File "/var/www/website.com/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 958, in _execute_context
    context)
  File "/var/www/website.com/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1159, in _handle_dbapi_exception
    exc_info
  File "/var/www/website.com/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 199, in raise_from_cause
    reraise(type(exception), exception, tb=exc_tb)
  File "/var/www/website.com/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 951, in _execute_context
    context)
  File "/var/www/website.com/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 436, in do_execute
    cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
  File "/var/www/website.com/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 205, in execute
    self.errorhandler(self, exc, value)
  File "/var/www/website.com/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 36, in defaulterrorhandler
    raise errorclass, errorvalue
OperationalError: (OperationalError) (2006, 'MySQL server has gone away') 'SELECT `Users`.id AS `Users_id`, `Users`.email AS `Users_email`, `Users`.password AS `Users_password`, `Users`.`emailConfirmed` AS `Users_emailConfirmed`, `Users`.`createdAtUtc` AS `Users_createdAtUtc`, `Users`.`updatedAtUtc` AS `Users_updatedAtUtc`, `Users`.`roleId` AS `Users_roleId` \nFROM `Users` \nWHERE `Users`.email = %s \n LIMIT %s' ('user@website.demo', 1)
2015-03-19 15:06:22,089 ERROR: Exception on /api/v1/account/login [POST] [in /var/www/website.com/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py:1423]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/www/website.com/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1817, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/var/www/website.com/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1477, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/var/www/website.com/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask_cors.py", line 272, in wrapped_function
    return cors_after_request(app.make_response(f(*args, **kwargs)))
  File "/var/www/website.com/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1381, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/var/www/website.com/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1475, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/var/www/website.com/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1461, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/var/www/website.com/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask_classy.py", line 200, in proxy
    response = view(**request.view_args)
  File "./webportal/account/api.py", line 34, in login_user
    user = auth.authenticate(username=email, password=password)
  File "/var/www/website.com/server/webportal/auth.py", line 23, in authenticate
    user = User.query.filter_by(email=username).first()
  File "/var/www/website.com/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 2367, in first
    ret = list(self[0:1])
  File "/var/www/website.com/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 2228, in __getitem__
    return list(res)
  File "/var/www/website.com/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 2438, in __iter__
    return self._execute_and_instances(context)
  File "/var/www/website.com/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 2453, in _execute_and_instances
    result = conn.execute(querycontext.statement, self._params)
  File "/var/www/website.com/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 729, in execute
    return meth(self, multiparams, params)
  File "/var/www/website.com/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/elements.py", line 322, in _execute_on_connection
    return connection._execute_clauseelement(self, multiparams, params)
  File "/var/www/website.com/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 826, in _execute_clauseelement
    compiled_sql, distilled_params
  File "/var/www/website.com/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 893, in _execute_context
    None, None)
  File "/var/www/website.com/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1159, in _handle_dbapi_exception
    exc_info
  File "/var/www/website.com/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 199, in raise_from_cause
    reraise(type(exception), exception, tb=exc_tb)
  File "/var/www/website.com/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 887, in _execute_context
    conn = self._revalidate_connection()
  File "/var/www/website.com/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 242, in _revalidate_connection
    "Can't reconnect until invalid "
StatementError: Can't reconnect until invalid transaction is rolled back (original cause: InvalidRequestError: Can't reconnect until invalid transaction is rolled back) u'SELECT `Users`.id AS `Users_id`, `Users`.email AS `Users_email`, `Users`.password AS `Users_password`, `Users`.`emailConfirmed` AS `Users_emailConfirmed`, `Users`.`createdAtUtc` AS `Users_createdAtUtc`, `Users`.`updatedAtUtc` AS `Users_updatedAtUtc`, `Users`.`roleId` AS `Users_roleId` \nFROM `Users` \nWHERE `Users`.email = %s \n LIMIT %s' [immutabledict({})]
```

According to https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/gone-away.html, MySQL closes the connection after 8 hours... Once that happens, the app gets in a bit of a state.

Comment: 500 means there is probably error log or stack trace somewhere available. Becaus the error appears daily, I think there must be some kind of resource leak (database connections, network connections). When the application runs out of resources it stops working.

Comment: @MikkoOhtamaa Well, the 500 I think is coming from my API code and that code only happens in a try/catch around db.session.commit(). If that fails, a 500 is returned. So, that means there is something with the sqlalchemy commit? Nginx doesn't have any errors, supervisord.log doesn't have errors... The app's application.log just shows an HTTP 500 (as expected). Any thoughts on why two uwsgi are spawned?

Comment: Can you please log the exception around the commit, so we do not need to guess? Please use Python file logging facilities if your stack does not log exceptions to files yet: https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html#logging-advanced-tutorial

Comment: @MikkoOhtamaa Good call. I had logging setup, but it doesn't seem to be complete. I realized that I'm not also logging from the sqlalchemy core. I'll set that up and report back when I run into the problem again

Comment: @MikkoOhtamaa The server went down again, and I grabbed the app log and added it. Seems there was a 'mysql went away' error... Which is interesting...

Comment: sounds like your database gets overloaded or runs out of connections

Comment: As a temporary solution try increase maximum database connections

Comment: @MikkoOhtamaa Thanks. As it's my dev server that's only hit sporadically, it looks like it's a timeout and MySQL is closing the connection. I've seen a couple of fixes, but they're complete hacks ('approved' hacks, mind you, but hacks nonetheless - e.g. pinging the DB before using it).

Comment: I've tried the SQLALCHEMY_POOL_RECYCLE=3600 fix that a lot of people mention, and it still doesn't work.

Comment: Then I suggest the next rock to turn around is "how to debug MySQL". I'd say settings a log level more verbose is a good start, install performance monitoring (Munin is the most low level entry) and start monitoring your MySQL instances.

Comment: @MikkoOhtamaa: Your comment inspired me to go back through everything with a fine toothed comb. I installed MariaDB with all the defaults, made no tweaks, and saw that the wait_timeout in my interactive session was always 8 hours (as expected). However, looking closer, it seems my global wait_timeout is/was 10 minutes (was originally 8 hours, but at some point, some update must have changed it [I never touch my.cnf in my code/provisioning]). I'm editing it, and trying again!

Comment: So, turns out NOTHING fixed this problem. What I ended up doing is putting an app.error_handler locked against 500 errors, putting in a session.rollback() and just suffering sporadic 500 errors infrequently. NOT cool, but 'works'